# commit on Github a scss file

Tags: git, file-permissions, github-pages

I'm building a website with Jekyll and GitHub pages.
I included a folder `scss` that contains `.scss files`. When I try to commit those changes on Github, I can't do a commit because an error appears.

Page named `contact.md` is  a markdown where I used those files.

Error looks like this:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    css/font-awesome/scss/

error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
error: pages/contact.md: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file pages/contact.md
fatal: updating files failed
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

use `` chown -R `whoami` .git `` to change owner (for permission)

Comment: what are the results of this command? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You don't have permission on your .git subtree (so you can't manage your versioned source code)
chown permits to change the proprietary of a file or a tree. whoami permits to specify the current user